# Amazon ElasticBeanStalk Worker Tier cannot connect to SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Currently I'm having issues to allow my worker to connect to SQS. Here is the log:

```
2014-07-21T21:37:26Z error: AWS::SQS::Errors::AccessDenied: Access to the resource https://sqs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/343152361204/dev-compose-request is denied.
```

**dev-compose-request** is the name of the Queue.

I *am* able to post messages from my other ElasticBeanStalk WebApp (server-tier) into this Queue.

My Worker Tier is in a security-group which allows any outbound connection.

Comment: Oddly enough, a plain vanilla Worker-Tier with a sample Queue also get these access denied errors.

Comment: I am seeing the same behavior.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sounds similar to: [AWS Beanstalk Worker can't start SQS daemon aws-sqsd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740441/aws-beanstalk-worker-cant-start-sqs-daemon-aws-sqsd)

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.iam.roles.aeb.html#AWSHowTo.iam.policies.actions.worker

Can you make sure the IAM Instance profile associated with your environment (may be named aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role but could be named something else as well) has all permissions listed in the link above?
(Copied below for reference)

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "QueueAccess",
      "Action": [
        "sqs:ChangeMessageVisibility",
        "sqs:DeleteMessage",
        "sqs:ReceiveMessage"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "MetricsAccess",
      "Action": [
        "cloudwatch:PutMetricData"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```