# how to disable sqs on elastic beanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, delayed-job, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-sqs

I have a rails app on AWS Elastic Beanstalk.  I process background tasks using delayed_job.  I set up an eb worker instance to handle this.  It works but shows as failed (red) in the dashboard.  I believe this is because of the following error that I get every few seconds:

```
error: AWS::SQS::Errors::AccessDenied: Access to the resource https://sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/xxx...xxxx is denied
```

I tried to remove sqs by means of the following to no avail:

```
services:
  sysvinit:
    aws-sqsd:
      enabled: false
      ensureRunning: false
```

How do I stop sqs? Ideally it would never be installed in the first place.  If I can't modify the install configuration is there a way to prevent this error from affecting the status of my environment?

Comment: You will have nginx even with worker environment. Can you explain your usecase in a bit more detail?

Comment: Sure, Thanks - I have a Rails app which processes background tasks using delayed_job.  So my worker just needs to run rails (for paperclip and delayed_job) with access to the app database and an internet connection.  The worker will need to download .wav files from s3, process them using ffmpeg, then upload them back to s3.  So I don't need to respond to http requests.

Comment: Probably, all I really need is Ruby.  But I have been unable to remove rails and keep my gems happy, so for right now I would like to get the worker running with Rails and perhaps thin it down further later.  I greatly appreciate any help you are able to provide

Comment: Ideally I would recommend using Web Server environment for this usecase. With a worker environment you get extra resources like SQS queue which you don't need. There is also a background daemon which runs on EC2 instances. This daemon polls the SQS queue. You don't need these resources. I would recommend using a Web Server environment for your usecase.

Comment: o.k. I will take your advise.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: @laertiades Did you ever solve this? I have a very similar situation (using Sidekiq) and want to disable both `sqs` related daemons and health checks as well as any web related services, such as Nginx or Passenger.

Comment: @BryanLiff No, I use Web Server environments now.

Comment: @BryanLiff did you manage to disable the aws-sqsd services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are launching a worker tier environment. That is why SQS is being created for your environment. You should launch a "Web Server" environment if you do not want to launch a worker environment. Worker Tier environment in Elastic Beanstalk allows you to poll messages from an SQS queue periodically.

Read more about worker tier environments here:
http://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/background-task-handling-for-aws-elastic-beanstalk/

Read more about environment tiers here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-tiers.html

If you want to use a Worker Tier environment with SQS enabled you can get rid of the AccessDenied exception by giving access to the IAM instance profile to access SQS as explained here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24880344/161628

Comment: Thank you Sir.  I enabled the queue using the IAM policy.  I figured there would be more unneccesary services if I used a web server such as Nginx.

Comment: You will have nginx even with worker environment. Can you explain your usecase in a bit more detail?